# Rails 3.0.20 bamboo to cedar migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bamboo, cedar

I am about to migrate from the Bamboo stack to the Cedar stack on Heroku. My app has Rails version 3.0.20 and Ruby version 1.93.
Does Cedar support Rails version 3.0.20? If not, what is the earliest version of rails supported by Cedar? Trying to figure out if I need to upgrade my rails version in order to use the Cedar stack.

Any answers/links/references would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Rails (3) version should be fine but, unless I've misread the [related Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3), [Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) requires Ruby 2.0.0 (it could be that their getting started docs are requiring Ruby 2.x just for the tutorials).

Given the base box/OS used on Cedar (Ubuntu 10.04), it's hard to imagine 1.9.3 would not run. That said, and for what it's worth, I've upgrade three different Rails 3.x apps from 1.9.3 to 2.0.0 and then 2.1.1 with zero problems.